# Android proguard Expected [!]interface|@interface|class|enum

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, proguard

**I have enabled proguard and getting error Expected [!]interface|@interface|class|enum**

Tried these

```
 -keep interface * {<methods>;}
```

and

```
-keep @interface *
```

and

```
-whyareyoukeeping @interface *
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'll ned to add the package route to your file:

So if It were at `com.example` , you should keep it like this:

```
-keep public interface com.example.Class$interface {*;}
```

`Class` Being the file in which your interface is.

Hope it helps :)